# CSS border height incosistent

Tags: css

i am building a page, and in the css i set a border of 1 pixel. But in the frontend, the border-height is incosistent.

[image]

The last border stripe is definitley bigger then the others.Does anybody know why this is?

CSS: border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.125)

Comment: https://chenhuijing.com/blog/about-subpixel-rendering-in-browsers/

Comment: Please provide [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (code) so we can help you.

Comment: See the article linked by @cbroe for an explanation and are you seeing differences when you zoom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with the property outline.

```css
outline: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.125);
```